# how to update data on fragment when user change the page by using ViewPager from FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am looking for great solution for update the fragment content when user change the page with the help of ViewPager that is implemented on FragmentActivity.I have implemented FragementActivity as follows:
         **InformationActivity extends FragmentACtivity**

```
 List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
  private void initialisePaging() {
         for(int i=0;i<getCount;i++){
                fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, DetailInfoFragment.class.getName()));
         }          
        this.mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
        pager.setCurrentItem(itemNumber);

        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                Log.v("onPageSelected", "arg0 "+arg0);

                MyAdapter getVal = new MyAdapter(InformationActivity.this);
                Log.v("InformationActivity ", "getTitle : == > "+getVal.titles[arg0]);
                Log.v("InformationActivity ", "getSubTitle : == > "+getVal.subTitles[arg0]);

                getSharedPreferences("Values", 0).edit().putString("Title", getVal.titles[arg0]).commit();
                getSharedPreferences("Values", 0).edit().putString("SubTitle", getVal.subTitles[arg0]).commit();
                getSharedPreferences("Values", 0).edit().putInt("Image", getVal.images[arg0]).commit();

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


    }
```

I have used shared preference for share the data in between Activity and Fragments.

I have implemented DetailInfoFragment extends Fragments as follows:

```
        @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View f1Vew = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, false);
    imageIcon = ((ImageView)f1Vew.findViewById(R.id.imagLrg));
    titleTxt = ((TextView)f1Vew.findViewById(R.id.titleText));
    subTxt = ((TextView)f1Vew.findViewById(R.id.subTitleText));
            String titleMain = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Values", 0).getString("Title", "");
    String subMain = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Values", 0).getString("SubTitle", "");

    Log.v("DetailInfoFragment : ", "tilte : "+titleMain);
    Log.v("DetailInfoFragment : ", "subMain : "+subMain);

    titleTxt.setText(""+titleMain);
    subTxt.setText(""+subMain);
    imageIcon.setImageResource(getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Values", 0).getInt("Image", 0));
    return f1Vew;
}
```

From the above implementation i am getting same title and sub title from InformationActivity to DetailsFragment when user swipe on page with the help of view pager.But my issue here is The Fragment content is not updating(titleTxt,subTxt,imageIcon) with title,sub title,image icon.please how can i update fragment content in my case